# set row_number start with 0

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, window-functions, row-number

Hi I am trying spark window function. I need to start the row_number from "0". Here is my code.

```
val target2 = target1.select("id","name","mark1","mark2","version").withColumn("rank", row_number().over(Window.partitionBy("name","mark1","mark2").orderBy("id")))
```

The row number is starting from "1". I tried like this.

```
val target2 = target1.select("id","name","mark1","mark2","version").withColumn("rank", row_number().over(Window.partitionBy("name","mark1","mark2").orderBy("id") -1))

val target2 = target1.select("id","name","mark1","mark2","version").withColumn("rank", row_number().over(Window.partitionBy("name","mark1","mark2").orderBy("id"))) -1
```

Not works for me. I need to start my row_number from zero. any help would be appreciated.

Comment: `withColumn("rank" , $"rank" - 1)`

Comment: Can you provide the full query because I am getting error

Comment: `target2.withColumn("rank" , $"rank" - 1)`

Answer (score 1):

**With Spark 2.4 it is**

```
val target2 = target1.select("id","name","mark1","mark2","version")
             .withColumn("rank",  
              row_number.over(Window.partitionBy("name","mark1","mark2") 
             .orderBy("id")) - 1)
```

Here it is reducing relative record number by 1

Answer (score 0):

Try this one:

```
w = Window.partitionBy("name","mark1","mark2").orderBy("id") 
target2 = target1.select("id","name","mark1","mark2","version").withColumn("rank",
                         row_number().over(w)-1)
```

It works with PySpark.